# How come calling UDP non-blocking socket RECVFROM take up to 30 milliseconds

Tags: time, udp

My system uses UDP communication between about 40 computers which most of them contains multiple network cards that connected to different VLANS.
Some of the messages are multicast and some unicast.
Mostly the time of RECVFROM (non-blocking UDP) is some micro seconds, but from time to time it can get into 2 to 30 milliseconds.
What could be the reason for such behavior?

Comment: A task switch that occurred, and another running program that got a time slice between the begin and the end of the call?

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to go out a limb and say that you're not running on an RTOS.  As a result, your application is just one of many user applications all in competition for the CPU.  What more than likely happened is another application stole the CPU from yours and you had to wait.

I would highly recommend reading up on the Linux scheduler.  Here's a good starting point: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-completely-fair-scheduler/.